# Does Intellij support wro4j?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, spring-boot, wro4j

I started programming in Java using Eclipse a few years ago, but then I had the opportunity to work with Intellij and I'm happier with it, because it's more performant, even though it has less plugins.

My problem is that now I'm working with [`wro4j`](http://wro4j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in a SpringBoot application. When I run the spring boot app from the IDE, the resources managed by `wro4j` do not seem to be downloaded, so I guess this is because I need to enable something for Intellij to work with `wro4j`, since, I know, there's [a plugin](https://github.com/jbosstools/m2e-wro4j) for Eclipse to work with `wro4j`. Is there such a thing for Intellij?

Currently, to make my project work as expected, i.e. resources are downloaded, etc, I need to install and run it from the terminal with the following commands:

1. `mvn clean install`
2. `mvn spring-boot:run`

Also my `wro.xml` file looks like this:

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
    <group name="angular-bootstrap">
        <css>webjar:bootstrap/3.3.7-1/less/bootstrap.less</css>
        <css>file:@project.basedir@/src/main/wro/main.less</css>
        <js>webjar:jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js</js>
        <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js</js>
        <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js</js>
        <js>webjar:angularjs/1.4.9/angular-cookies.min.js</js>
    </group>
</groups>
```

and the `http://www.isdc.ro/wro` is colored red with the warning:

> URI is not registered

but this is because, I think, I've not `wro4j` as a dependency but as a plugin. In fact, if I also add it as a dependency, the warning disappears, but I still have the problem that dependencies are not downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by providing the location of the XML Schema (XSD).

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isdc.ro/wro https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wro4j/wro4j/1.8.x/wro4j-core/src/main/resources/ro/isdc/wro/wro.xsd">
```

In this case, I pointed to the XSD located in the project's GitHub page in [raw format](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wro4j/wro4j/1.8.x/wro4j-core/src/main/resources/ro/isdc/wro/wro.xsd).

After fetching the external resource you should have everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing Intellij with wro4j and SpringBoot and I got the same issue. The only step to stop this error is go to:

File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Schemas and DTDs

Press the green cross in the "Ignored Schemas and DTDs" section and add: http://www.isdc.ro/wro

I hope this help you.